# Unable to get Oauth2 TokenSource to refresh a token retrieved from storage

Tags: go, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

After a user authorizes Google Calendar, the NodeJS service saves the **Code, AccessToken and RefreshToken** to a storage.

Trying to use the same token to access the users' calendar using different backend service written in Go. 
When the AccessToken is valid, the data is accessible, but when AccessToken expires unable to get the config.Exchange() or config.TokenSource() to give a new token which works, even though the token is valid, when trying to access events, get error :

> Error 401: Invalid Credentials, authError exit status 1

```
 tok, err := config.TokenSource(ctx, token).Token() // token is previous valid token
 if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve token from web: %v", err)
 }
```

Also tried to exchange code for a new token but doesn't help

> 400 Bad Request
>   Response: {
>     "error": "invalid_grant",
>     "error_description": "Malformed auth code."
>   }

```
    tok, err := config.Exchange(context.TODO(), in)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve token from web: %v", err)
}
```

Trying to access using calendar.NewService

```
srv, _ := calendar.NewService(ctx, option.WithTokenSource(config.TokenSource(ctx, tok)))
```

How to get a token which can access offline without user intervention from another service ?

**Update: Storing token to Redis - RedisJSON but still won't get a new AccessToken. This is the complete function where I am passing a valid Token. It works only before AccessToken expiry.**

```
func GetGoogleCalendarEvents(token *oauth2.Token, userid string) *calendar.Events {
tok := &oauth2.Token{}
var config *oauth2.Config
ctx := context.Background()

b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("credentials.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
}

config, err = google.ConfigFromJSON(b, calendar.CalendarScope) //calendar.CalendarScope)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
}

tok = token

if token.Expiry.Before(time.Now()) {

    tokenSource := config.TokenSource(ctx, token) //oauth2.NoContext

    newToken, err := tokenSource.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    if tok.AccessToken != newToken.AccessToken {
        SetAuthCredToCache(userid, tok)
        tok = newToken
        fmt.Println(newToken)
    }
}

fmt.Println(tok.Expiry, tok.Valid(), tok.Type(), tok.RefreshToken, tok.TokenType)

srv, _ := calendar.NewService(ctx, option.WithTokenSource(config.TokenSource(ctx, tok)))

t := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)

events, err := srv.Events.List("primary").ShowDeleted(true).
    SingleEvents(true).TimeMin(t).OrderBy("startTime").Do()

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve next ten of the user's events: %v", err)
}
return events
```

}

Comment: Show the code where the token is saved and loaded.

Comment: Remembering the authorization code is pointless: "If an authorization code is used more than once, the authorization server MUST deny the request" https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.2

Comment: hi @CeriseLimón. I am storing it to Redis as string. Code, AccessToken, RefreshToken.

Comment: Save and restore the entire token by serializing to and from JSON.  Does the application save the token returned from a refresh?

Comment: Thanks, will try that. No, the application doesn't save, was trying with new token every time to see if it works. But will save the refreshed token now and update.

Comment: Still unable to get it to work, added the function where I am trying to get events.

Answer (score 1):

It was an Unmarshalling problem.

When saving token from Node, it serializes expiry time as **"expiry_date"** and Go Token has json representation as just **"expiry"** . Unmarshalling the rest of the object to oauth2.Token object and adding expiry time to that object solved the problem.